# SwiftUI bug when displaying multiple line value on left side and which breaks alignment on right side in stack

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, sections

I'm facing an alignment issue when text input is multiple lines. In this example, the first section shows the left and right side text properly shown in the image. the second section, it shows text in 3 to 4 lines which disturb the alignment right side

I want to make the left make independently size during multiple lines. The right side remains as it is(no gap between `2nd title` and `2nd Value` ).

Code of my view :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {

            Section {
                Text("single line")
            }
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "Value",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "test",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            Section {
                Text("mutiple lines")
            }
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "This is long. This is long value. This is long value",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "test",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


struct TwoLineView: View{
    var firstTitle: String
    var fistValue: String
    var secondTitle: String
    var secondValue: String
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(firstTitle).lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                
                Text(fistValue)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(secondTitle).lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                
                Text(secondValue).lineLimit(1)
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 45)
        }
    }
}
```

Expected:
Single or multiple line values. I don't want to display a gap between the title and value. (2nd section in the image has a gap between `2nd title` and `2nd Value`  which is a bad UX experience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Text("single line")
            }
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "Value",
                        secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "Test",
                        secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            Section {
                Text("mutiple lines")
            }
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "This is long. This is long value. This is long value",
                        secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "Test",
                        secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
        }
    }
}
struct TwoLineView: View{
    var firstTitle: String
    var fistValue: String
    var secondTitle: String
    var secondValue: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(firstTitle).lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                
                Text(fistValue)
                Spacer() // add
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(secondTitle).lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                
                Text(secondValue).lineLimit(1)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 45)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind checking on updated question ?
It still shows small alignment problem on my side

Comment: let me know the problem.

Comment: the problem is unnecessary vertical gap between in "1st Title" and "Value" , "1st Title" and "Test" for  single line. For multiple line, "1st Title" and "test" there is unnecessary vertical gap

Comment: I updated this code in the question

Comment: I updated answer remove `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` and add `Spacer`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `frame` and add `spacer` in `VStack`.

```
         HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center, spacing: 0) {
                    VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                        Text("1st Title ").lineLimit(1)
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                        
                        Text("This is long value. This is long value. This is long value")
                        
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                        Text("2nd title").lineLimit(1)
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                        
                        Text("2nd Value").lineLimit(1)
                        Spacer() //here
                    //.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    }
                    Spacer(minLength: 45)
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for input here. This solves issues and display what I need. But, one problem is it breaks alignment in the Bottom right bo

Comment: For that, you have to add `Spacer(minLength: 45)` in the outer spacer. I edited my answer please check

Comment: You have to give some value to the spacer in every row

Comment: or you have to give some ```minWidth``` to a multi-line text frame.

Comment: please check I have added another post.